# why is my classList applying in all icons

Tags: javascript

I have 3 heart icons. I want to add a class to each icon, the class is stored in Localstorage.

When I refresh the page, the class is added to all 3 icons, but I want to select only one to be active.

```js
const heart = document.querySelectorAll('.icons .fa-heart');
let classr = localStorage.getItem("class");

heart.forEach((x) => {
  if (classr !== null) {
    x.classList.toggle(classr);
  }
  x.addEventListener("click", () => {
    x.classList.toggle("active");
    localStorage.setItem("class", "active");
  });
});
```

Comment: because you assign it to all of them in the loop.... There is nothing in your code that is setting what one is active. You are just setting a generic class there.

Comment: @epascarello
yes I know but how do I target select one

Comment: give the element a name, an id, a data attribute. Read that and save it. When you loop, check what one is selected and add the class.

Comment: Do you need to remember each one or is only one that can be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the class in the local storage, but what you want to store is a way of identifying the heart that has been selected.

If you don't want to give each heart an ID, then you should be able to use the index of the item in the children collection of their parent.

```js
(function()
{
  let heartsContainer = document.getElementById('hearts');
  for(let hi = 0; hi < heartsContainer.children.length; hi++)
  {
    let heart = heartsContainer.children[hi];
    
    let gotValue = localStorage.getItem(hi);
    
    if(gotValue !== null && gotValue === 'true')
    {
      heart.classList.toggle('empty');
      heart.classList.toggle('full');      
    }
    
    heart.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
      e.target.classList.toggle('empty');
      e.target.classList.toggle('full');
      
      let storedValue = localStorage.getItem(hi);
      
      if(storedValue !== null)
      {
        localStorage.setItem(hi, !(storedValue==='true'));
      }
      else
      {
        localStorage.setItem(hi, true);
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
.empty::before
{
  content:'♡';
}
.full::before
{
  content:'♥';
}
```

```html
<div id="hearts">
<p class="empty"></p>
<p class="empty"></p>
<p class="empty"></p>
</div>
```

(The snippet won't work because of security issues, but you can see it working on codepen: https://codepen.io/schmellen/pen/BaOyMmL)

`if(storedValue !== null)` checks if there is an entry in the localStorage already for that number. If the entry is not `null` then it exist, so it only needs toggling.

If the entry does not exist (the value is `null`), and given the default state for a heart is "empty", the first time the entry is created, the entry should be `true` because the heart will be filled.

Comment: yes Its worked now but I dont understant if else codition that you have put can you please explain @Matt Ellen

Comment: @swadhin I've updated the answer. does that explanation help?

Comment: yes i understood little bit right now i am in learning phase so i am trying create little project by myself but whenever i tried its getting something error and the most biggest problem is i dont know how to ask proper question and my poor english. its almost 3 months i tried to learn js by myself @Matt Ellen